# Android Studio: How to configure Java module to contain embedded resources?

Tags: java, android-studio, jar, classpath

I have a few XML files that I want to be included within the JAR file.

Where do I put these files within my module and how do I tell Android Studio to add them to the JAR when I compile?

In code, how do I get a hold of these files using the [`java.io.File`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) APIs?

Remember, though I'm on Android Studio, I'm talking about a plain Java module, not an Android one.

Comment: Please read the tag descriptions. Android is not "embedded" as of the meaning used by SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much research and headache, here's the solution I found:

1- In Android Studio, toggle to "Project" view.
[image]

2- Add a directory to the root of the module. Call it something like "assets"; this is where your resources will go.
[image]

3- Add your resources to the directory.
[image]

4- In your module's Gradle file add `sourceSets.main.resources.srcDirs = [ "assets/" ]` at the top.
[image]

5- Your files are now bundled inside the jar when you compile. In code you can now get an `InputStream` that references a file by doing:

```
ClassLoader classLoader = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
InputStream inputStream = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("stages/stage_1/map.tmx");
```